# How to use dup and or dup2 to redirect standard out into a pipe, then out to antoher pipe and then back out to standard out?

Tags: c, pipe, stdout, dup2, dup

Ok guys, there are a billion demos relating to dup, dup2, fcntl, pipe and all kinds of stuff that are wonderful when multiple processes exist.  However, I have yet to see one very basic thing that I think will help explain the behavior of pipe and its relationship to standard out and in.

My goal is to simply (in the same process) reroute standard output through a pipe back to standard output directly.  I have already accomplished this
with intermediate stages which redirect the pipe output to a file or write into a buffer... and then put standard output back to where it started.  At that point, of course I can write the buffer back to stdout, but I don't want to do this.

Since I moved standard output to another location in the file table, I'd like to direct the output of the pipe to feed directly into the new standard output position and have it print like it normally would.

I feel like there is some kind of layer surrounding the file table that I am not understanding.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main() {
    int pipeEnds_arr1[2];

    char str1[] = "STRING TO FEED INTO PIPE \n"; // make a string array

    pipe(pipeEnds_arr1);

    printf("File Descriptor for pipe ends from array\nPOSITION out  0 : %d\nPOSITION in 1 : %d\n", pipeEnds_arr1[0], pipeEnds_arr1[1]);


    /* now my goal is to shift the input of the pipe into the position of 
     * standard output, so that the print command feeds the pipe, then I 
     * would like to redirect the other end of the pipe to standard out. 
     */

    int someInt = dup(1); // duplicates stdout to next available file table position

    printf ("Some Int FD: %d\n", someInt); // print out the fd for someInt just for knowing where it is

    /* This is the problem area.  The out end of the pipe never 
     * makes it back to std out, and I see no way to do so.  
     * Stdout should be in the file table position 5, but when 
     * I dup2 the output end of the pipe into this position , 
     * I believe I am actually overwriting std out completely.  
     * But I don't want to overwrite it, i want to feed the output
     * of the pipe into std out. I think I am fundamentally 
     * misunderstanding this issue. 
     */

    dup2(pipeEnds_arr1[1], 1); //put input end of pipe into std out position
    //dup2(pipeEnds_arr1[0], 5); // this will not work
    //and other tests I have conducted do not work


    printf("File Descriptor for pipe ends from array\nPOSITION out  0 : %d\nPOSITION in 1 : %d\n", pipeEnds_arr1[0], pipeEnds_arr1[1]);

    fflush(stdout);

    close(pipeEnds_arr1[0]);
    close(pipeEnds_arr1[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT*********
OK, what I know is that somehow std out takes information from commands like printf and then routs it into a buffer that is then flushed to the shell.

What I believe is that there must be a way to rout the "read" or output end of the pipe to that same buffer that then gets to the shell. I have figured out how to rout the pipe output into a string, and then I can do as I please.  In the example code I post below, I will first rout the pipe out to a string and then open a file and write the string to the open file descriptor of that file...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>


int main() {
    /*  Each pipe end array has to have 2 positions in it.  The array
     *  position represents the two pipe ends with the 0 index
     *  position representing the output of the pipe (the place you want
     *  read your data from), and 1 index position representing the
     *  input file descriptor of the pipe (the place you want to write
     *  your data).
     */
    int pipeEnds_arr1[2];

    char str1[] = "Hello, we are feeding this into the pipe that we are through stdout into a pipe and then reading from the pipe and then feeding that output into a file \n"; // make a string array

    /*  Here we want to actually do the pipe command. We feed it the array
     *  with the 2 positions in it which will now hold file descriptors
     *  attached to the current process which allow for input and output
     *  through the new pipe. At this point, we don't know what the
     *  exact file decriptors are, but we can look at them by printing
     */

    pipe(pipeEnds_arr1);
    printf("File Descriptor for pipe ends from array\nPOSITION out  0 : %d\nPOSITION in 1 : %d\n", pipeEnds_arr1[0], pipeEnds_arr1[1]);

    /* now my goal is to shift the input of the pipe into the position of 
     * standard output, so that the print command feeds the pipe, then we
     * will try to read from the pipe and redirect the output to the std 
     * or in this test case out to a file.
     */

    int someInt = dup(1); // we moved what was stdout into someInt;

    /* put the write end of the pipe in the old stdout position by
     * using dup2 so we will print directly into the pipe
     */
    dup2(pipeEnds_arr1[1], 1);

    /* this is where id like to re-rout the pipe back to stdout but
     * im obviously not understanding this correctly
     */
    //dup2(someInt, 3);

    /* since std out has now been replaced by the pipe write end, this
     * printf will print into the pipe
     */
    printf("%s", str1);


    /* now we read from the pipe into a new string we make */
    int n;
    char str2[strlen(str1)];
    n = read(pipeEnds_arr1[0], str2, sizeof(str2)-1);
    str2[n] = 0;

    /* open a file and then write into it from the output of the pipe 
     * that we saved into the str2
     */
    int fd = open("tmp.out", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0644);
    write(fd, str2, strlen(str2));


    /* not sure about these last commands and their relevance */
    fflush(stdout);
    close(pipeEnds_arr1[0]);
    close(pipeEnds_arr1[1]);
    close(fd);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Standard output is *always* file descriptor `1`. What you have in `someInt` is a descriptor that is different from descriptor `1` after your `dup2` call. The `dup` system calls really *duplicates* the descriptors, it doesn't use references or links or anything like that. Also, the `dup` calls doesn't modify the descriptor numbers you pass. `pipeEnds_arr1[1]` will not change value (the descriptor number) anytime after the `pipe` call.

Comment: This can't work in any case. One end of the pipe is for writing, the other end is for reading. So you can replace `stdout` with the write end of the pipe, and your program can write stuff into the pipe (thinking that it's writing to `stdout`). But the other end of the pipe can't be directly connected to the original `stdout`. Some piece of code needs to read from the pipe and write the data to the original `stdout`.

Comment: This can't work even in theory, because it would create an infinite loop. Think about it - you would end up feeding the output from stdout back into itself.

Comment: @user3386109 somehow std out takes information from commands like printf and then routs it into the buffer that is then flushed to the shell.  There must be a way to rout the "read" or output end of the pipe to that same buffer that then gets to the shell.  What do you mean by "some piece of code by the way?"  I have figured out how to rout the pipe output into a string, and then I can do as I please, but there is still something missing from my understanding because it doesn't seem like it should be necessary to rout the output to something else and THEN send that out...? should be one step.

Comment: @user6840486 I'm the same guy you're talking to under rici's answer. I'm waiting for you to post the code that shows how you *"can fairly easily rout my standard output to a file through a pipe in the same process"*. The code that routs the pipe output into a string would also be interesting.

Comment: @user3386109 roger that updated.

Comment: Ok, so you call `read` to extract the message from the pipe and store it in the string, and then you call `write` to take the message out of the string and store it in the file. That's what I mean by *"some piece of code"*. That is the code that reads from the pipe and writes the data to the file. So as long as you have the original `stdout` file descriptor saved somewhere, you can do the same thing to read from the pipe and write to the original `stdout` file descriptor.

Comment: @user3386109  so no way to go from pipe directly to the buffer that feeds the console?  This probably would have been a better way to pose the question than my initial way.

Comment: Nope. Think of the pipe as a read-only file, as if you did `int fdin=open("tmp.in",O_RDONLY)`. And the console is a write-only file, as if you did `int fdout=open("tmp.out",O_WRONLY)`. Those two file descriptors aren't going to talk to each other. If you want them to talk, you need code to `read` from one and `write` to the other.

Answer (score 2):

Pipes aren't between file descriptors. They are between processes. So it doesn't make any sense to "reroute standard out through a pipe".

What you can do is modify a process's file descriptor table so that its stdout (fd 1) is the write side of a pipe. And you can modify another process's file descriptor table so that some file descriptor, perhaps even stdin (fd 0) is the read side of the same pipe. That allows you to pass data through the pipe between the two processes. (You can set up a pipe between two fds in the same process, if you want to; it's occasionally useful but watch out for deadlocking.)

`stdout` is not some sort of magical entity. It's just entry 1 in the fd table, and it might refer to any "file", in the Unix sense of the word, which includes regular files, devices (including the console and the pseudoterminal your shell is communicating with), sockets, pipes, FIFOs, and whatever else the operating system feels worthy of allowing streaming access to.

Normally, when the shell starts a running a command-line utility, it first clones fds 0, 1 and 2 (stdin, stdout and stderr) from its own fd 0, 1, and 2, which are normally all the same device: the console, or more commonly these days, the pseudoterminal provided by the graphical console application you are using. But you can change those assignments with, for example, shell redirection operators, shell pipe operators, and some shell-provided special files.

Finally, pipes do have small buffers in the kernel, but the key is rhe word "small" -- the buffer might hold as little as 4096 bytes. If gets full, attempts to write to the pipe will hang until space becomes available, which only happens when data is read from the other sude. That's why it is so easy to deadlock if the same process is using both sides of the pipe: if the process is hanging waiting for the pileto be emptied, it wikk neverbe able to read the pipe.

Comment: I'm not quite sure why you say pipes can only be between different processes.  I can fairly easily rout my standard output to a file through a pipe in the same process.  So what about feeding the pipe from standard out and using it as a buffer, and then redirecting the output end of the pipe to back to standard out?  I still don't understand why this can't happen.

I am fairly certain I routed the print statement into the pipe properly, and since the pipe is behaving like a buffer, I should be able to send that buffer back out to the console somehow?

Comment: *"I can fairly easily rout my standard output to a file through a pipe in the same process."* It would help if you added that code to the question @user6840486 .

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit new to this.  How should I go about adding this code?  Should I post it as an edit, or add it somewhere else? @user3386109

Comment: *"Should I post it as an edit"* Yup, add a paragraph that says what you said in the comment above, and then tack on the code after that @user6840486

Comment: @user6840486: you persist in thinking that stdout is a thing. It isn't; it's simply the number 1,and used as an index into the array of open "files". A pipe is one possible file. A console is another possibility. And if course, there are disk files. Etc. When you dup2 a pipe into "stdout", all you do is, in effect, is ask the io library to do an assignment: `fds[1] = fds[pipe]`. A pipe is actually two files, one at each end, so you can use it to tunnel data by writing to one end and reading the other. That really has nothing to do with stdout; except that `printf` always writes to fd 1.